# How to limit Chrome Extension installation on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, applescript, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to remove the user's ability to install extension in Chrome on Mac OS. I found the ExtensionInstallBlacklist policy but can't figure out how to actually make it start working. Any tips?

And does anyone know of a way to disable the ability to sign into Chrome/change profile/user?

Thanks in advance!

Jared

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Set app and extension policies for Mac](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7517624?hl=en) guide.

> **Update configuration policy**
>
> You can set the ExtensionSettings policy
> on Mac computers using [configuration
> profiles](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/mac-quick-start).
> When you install the configuration profile on a device, the settings
> are applied. To set specific app and extension policies for the
> profile, see Customize app and extension policies.
>
> Check full guide with sample installation codes.

Answer (score 0):

This was a better example than on Googles docs for me on Ubuntu:  https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions

```
Mac
The policies for the extension can be configured via MCX preferences for the com.google.Chrome.extensions.gihmafigllmhbppdfjnfecimiohcljba bundle, or for the org.chromium.Chromium.extensions.gihmafigllmhbppdfjnfecimiohcljba bundle if using Chromium. This can be done by creating a plist file with the configuration and importing it using dscl:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>com.google.Chrome.extensions.gihmafigllmhbppdfjnfecimiohcljba</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Bookmarks Bar</key>
    <dict>
      <key>state</key>
      <string>always</string>
      <key>value</key>
      <array>
        <dict>
          <key>title</key>
          <string>Chromium</string>
          <key>url</key>
          <string>chromium.org</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
          <key>title</key>
          <string>Videos</string>
          <key>children</key>
          <array>
            <dict>
              <key>title</key>
              <string>YouTube</string>
              <key>url</key>
              <string>youtube.com</string>
            </dict>
          </array>
        </dict>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/components/policy/resources/policy_templates.json
https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3/extension-settings-full
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions